# Alignment issues with Stack flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have design that shows flash offers count but when i tried to design like the following image the alignment of widgets do not work properly. How do i approach this design? I have tried many codes but i am not getting the desired results.

The design i am trying to create

[image]

The design i did so far

[image]

**Code**

```
  Widget FlashOffers(){
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FlashOfferListScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width:350,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))
              ),
            ),
            Center(child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Flash Offers",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            )),
            Row(
              // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/YELLOW.svg"),
                    Text("3")
                  ],
                ),

              ],),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```

Comment: you can achieve it without using stack

Comment: can you help me with code@FaiiziiAwan

Comment: I am wondering why yellow svg is rendering as black?

Comment: it is probably because of corrupted SVG file @UsamaKarim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example without using Stack. Hope you will get the idea and it will help :-)

```
return MaterialButton(elevation: 8,
    color: Colors.redAccent,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)
    ),
    child: Row(children: [
      Expanded(child: Text('FLASH OFFER', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow, radius: 12, child: Text("2"))
    ]),
    onPressed: () {
      print('button pressed');
    });
```

**Edit:** To show the shadow, use the elevation property of button. You can also change the shadow color

Comment: ok let me design a button for you i will update my answer

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check it. It resolves your widget positioning problem. To achieve the exact result, I think you can now do the customization :-) happy coding

Comment: it worked,but i have to additional customization,but it is more easy@Faiizii Awan

Comment: yeah it is quite easy using button widget. No need of stack ;-) 
Keep fluttering :-D

Comment: The problem with this approach will be the text won't be in exact center

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Remove your row widget and add alignment: Alignment.center to stack that is in the row. Wrap you Stack with Align Widget and add alignment: Alignment.centerRight

```
Widget flashOffers() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Container(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 350,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
            ),
            Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                "Flash Offers",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            )),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                   SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/YELLOW.svg"),
                   Text("3")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I dont think he needs to use stack widget to design this button

Comment: It won't do without stack. Stack is needed here for sure. because of the SvgPicture and for its alignment at the end of the button. Although The background of the button and Text can be made to one widget. but that is all.

Comment: It is a button widget Taha. and it will have a row widget as child. Row will have 2 children first one is Text and other will be the CircularAvatar with the customized background(as in the snippet, yellow one). Then the circular avatar will have the child a Text widget which display the number.
To do the alignment, you can use Spacer() or Flex the Text(button) and Text will be center aligned.

Comment: This works if i remove the svgpicture and using Container,if i use svg icon the alignment fails@TahaMalik

Comment: try to add width and height to svg picture.

Comment: or wrap your SvgPicture with a container, and give width height to that container

Comment: FaiiziAwan answered worked, but I didn't suggested that methods because if you implement like that your text won't be in exact center. If you are okay with that, then @FaiiziiAwan answer is great.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding the label and counter icon inside the container widget.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Widget flashOffers() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FlashOfferListScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 350,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Flash Offers",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/YELLOW.svg"),
                  Text("3"),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You just repeated my answer.

Comment: @TahaMalik I have removed the outer StackWidget, it is not needed

Comment: @Assassin whats the issue?

Comment: SvgPicture causing alignment problem still@yusufpats

Comment: it was problem with svg but ,I have got an easy answer by Faiizii Awan ,Thank you for your effort@yusufpats

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: flashOffers(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget flashOffers() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('new route push');
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          width: 350,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFFc1202e),
                  Color(0xFFea2127),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(30),
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(-10, 10),
                  color: Colors.black26,
                ),
              ]),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  "Flash Offers".toUpperCase(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.folder,
                    size: 30,
                    color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '3',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but  if i remove the Icon and using svgIcon ,if i use svg icon the alignment fails@TahaMalik

Comment: please use the png icon instead of svg. as I know so far, flutter doesnot support svg. To use svg icon you need to use external libs (i think)

Comment: @assasin add the link to the svg file, and I'll put it in my answer

Comment: I have got it easy way by Faiizii Awan,but thank you for effort @Kherel

Answer (score 0):

You can use positioned,it is so useful in stack widget.
Look at this:
[https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-widget-positioning-eca4fea1528b#:~:text=A%20Stack%20allows%20you%20to,the%20children%20of%20a%20stack](https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-widget-positioning-eca4fea1528b#:%7E:text=A%20Stack%20allows%20you%20to,the%20children%20of%20a%20stack).

Comment: i did with positioned didn't get the desired design@semih10

Comment: Did you try alignment property of stack?

Comment: yeah,i did that@semih10

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          ),
                          child: FlatButton(
                            splashColor: iconButton,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(20)),
                            color: primaryColor,
                            onPressed: () {
                              sendMail();
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                 Container(),
                                  Text(
                                    "Send",
                                    style: styleText(
                                        size: 20,
                                        weight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: white),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                  child:  Center(
                                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                        ic_profileWhite,
                                        height: 20,
                                        width: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```